# How to get the name of a file and how to add a new line before a specified line?

Tags: c#

I have a variable who get a destination:

```
var lin = (Path + "config.ini").ToString();
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(lin);
var InstallerFile = lines.Where(txt => txt.Contains("IstallerFile="))
                    .Select(txt => txt.Split('=')[1].Replace("\"", "")).FirstOrDefault();
```

after I run this code I will have: `InstallerFile=D:\folder\instaler.ini` or `InstallerFile=D:\folder\instaler_input.ini` this depend what I have in `config` file.
Now O copy that file in `C:\temp\` with this :

```
if (File.Exists(InstallerFile))
    System.IO.File.Copy(InstallerFile, @"C:\temp\");
```

and now I want to verify what name have the file, because the rows are different. Fore example if I have `installer.ini` I need to do this :

```
var modifiedLines = linesInst.Select(line =>
{
    if (line.StartsWith("destination="))
        return string.Format("destination=\"{0}", textBox1.Text);
    else
        return line;
});

File.WriteAllLines(InstallerFile, modifiedLines);
```

and if I have `installer_input.ini` I need to add a row on this file before the row who starts with `#product=MAtlab`.
So I have two question in one, how to get the name of a file and how to add a new line before a specified line ?

Comment: If this is a config file that allows users to set the configuration, then *why* does the logic depend on specific values there?!

Comment: because the installation is make with installer.ini file. Please you can give me an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the name of a file with this:

```
Path.GetFileName(path)
```

to Insert a new line before specific line you must read all file, when you find a specific line you push new element. The example code like this:

```
string path=Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"32901448","InputFle.txt");
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            List<string> linesOut = new List<string>();
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                if (line.ToUpper().Trim() == "BLUE")
                {
                    linesOut.Add("YELLOW");    
                }
                linesOut.Add(line);
            }

            File.WriteAllLines(path, linesOut);
```

Comment: what means this number "32901448" ?

Comment: and with this Path.GetFileName(path) you get all file names, and I need to verify if I have installer.ini or installer_input.ini

Comment: 32901448 is a sub folder where is my file ex: c:/32901448/InputFle.txt.

Comment: to verify if exist your file you may use File.Exists(your_path_file_name)